# Quality Center OTA API - how to read list of values from a User Field

Tags: list, vbscript, field, lookup, hp-quality-center

I'm using Quality Center 10, and have a question about retrieving data from a user field:

I have a Test User Field defined as TS_USER_15 as a "Customers" field from type "lookup List" which has several values.
How can I read these list of values from a VB script running as a test?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer by myself:

```
'Consider m_td_connection = TD_connection

Dim iGlobalListCounter, iListCounter, ValuesStr, ProductListName
ProductListName = "Status"
For iGlobalListCounter = 1 to m_td_connection.Customization.Lists.Count
    If m_td_connection.Customization.Lists.ListByCount(iGlobalListCounter).RootNode.Name = ProductListName Then
        ValuesStr = m_td_connection.Customization.Lists.ListByCount(iGlobalListCounter).RootNode.Children.Item(1).Name  ‘starting ValuesArr with the first value
        For iListCounter = 2 to m_td_connection.Customization.Lists.ListByCount(iGlobalListCounter).RootNode.ChildrenCount
            ValuesStr = ValuesStr & "," & m_td_connection.Customization.Lists.ListByCount(iGlobalListCounter).RootNode.Children.Item(iListCounter).Name
        Next
    End If
Next
Msgbox ProductListName & " list values = " & vbCrlf & ValuesStr
```